# How do I make a certain div scrollable if overflow-y: scroll is not working?

Tags: html, css, scroll, styles, height

So I'm doing a part of an app for my job and after figuring out all the programming part with ease, I've been stuck on its CSS for about 3hours now, and I can't figure out where the problem is. The thing is, I need to make a certain div scrollable, but when I add the overflow-y: scroll or auto tags, the scrollbar doesn't appear or appears greyed out, as if you couldn't scroll at all.

The thing is, the div isn't showing completely, and in order to see all of it you need to zoom out the page (I'll add some screenshots). So I've never really done heavy CSS before and I'm completely lost here, so I hope someone could give me some insight on this.

I'm using Vue.js on the app, idk if that's important or not really.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<template>
 <div class="aside-metrics">
   <div class="aside-header">
     <div class="aside-header-title-container">
       <h2>{{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.title`) }}</h2>
     <div class="route">
      <span>{{ assetInfo.plantId }} - {{ assetInfo.win }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-header-observations-container">
    {{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.subtitle`) }}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aside-content">
  <div
    v-if="!metrics || (!metrics.isFetching && !metrics.state)"
  >
    {{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.empty`) }}
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="metrics && metrics.isFetching">
    <spinner-component></spinner-component>
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="metrics && metrics.error">
    {{ metrics.errorDescription }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <div class="metric-chart">
      <div class="metric-chart-title">
        {{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.expenses.title`) }}
      </div>
      <div class="chart" ref="expenses-container" style="width: 100%">
        <div ref="chart__expenses" style="width: inherit">
          <div v-html="tooltips.expenses"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="metric-chart">
      <div class="metric-chart-title">
        {{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.failures.title`) }}
      </div>
      <div class="chart" ref="failures-container" style="width: 100%">
        <div ref="chart__failures" style="width: inherit">
          <div v-html="tooltips.failures"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="metric-chart">
      <div class="metric-chart-title">
        {{ $t(`modules.${assetsModule}.metrics.efficiency.title`) }}
      </div>
      <div class="chart" ref="efficiency-container" style="width: 100%">
        <div ref="chart__efficiency" style="width: inherit">
          <div v-html="tooltips.efficiency"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS part looks like this:

```
<style lang="scss">
 .k-tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -8px;
 padding: 0;
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 // margin-left: -15px;
 /*        position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    */

 > div {
   @include layout-flex;
   @include layout-vertical;
   @include layout-center-center;
   border-radius: 2px;
   padding: 8px;
   font-family: $mdc-typography-font-family;
 }  

 .tooltip {
@include layout-relative;
background-color: $white-color;

.value {
  font-size: $uxl-units-size-12;
  line-height: $uxl-units-size-12;
  color: $app-blue-700;
  font-weight: $font-weight-semi-bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 4px);
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid $white-color;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
}
}
```

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.aside-metrics {
@include animation-fade;
@include layout-flex;
@include layout-vertical;
height: 100%;

.aside-header {
@include layout-vertical;
@include layout-justified;
@include layout-start;
border-bottom: 1px solid $header-border-bottom-color;
min-height: 185px;
max-height: 185px;
padding: 40px 32px 0 32px;
box-sizing: border-box;

.aside-header-title-container {
  h2 {
    font-size: $uxl-units-size-28;
    line-height: $uxl-units-size-28;
    font-weight: $font-weight-semi-bold;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  }

  .route {
    font-size: $uxl-units-size-16;
    line-height: $uxl-units-size-16;
    font-weight: $font-weight-regular;
    color: $app-color-200;

    .separator {
      padding: 0 4px;
    }
  }
  }

.aside-header-observations-container {
  font-size: $uxl-units-size-14;
  line-height: $uxl-units-size-14;
  font-weight: $font-weight-regular;
  color: $app-color-500;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}
}

.aside-content {
@include layout-flex;
@include layout-vertical;
@include layout-justified;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding: 32px;

.metric-chart {
  @include layout-flex;
  @include layout-vertical;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(#747985, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  position: relative;

  &:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .metric-chart-title {
    font-size: $uxl-units-size-18;
    line-height: $uxl-units-size-18;
    font-weight: $font-weight-semi-bold;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
  }

  .chart {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  }
  }

  @media screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 21/9) {
  .aside-content {
  @include layout-flex-auto;
  @include layout-scroll;
  @include layout-start-justified;

  .metric-chart {
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  }
  }
  }
  </style>
```

I've not added the script of it cause I suppose it isn't necessary for my problem here.

This is how the webpage looks:

[image: Content appears cut off]

As you can see the content is cut off and the scrollbar greyed out.

If I zoom out you can see the whole content:

[image: Full content]

I really hope someone can lend me a hand because as of right now I've almost done everything I could think of.

Comment: That's not your html, it's your template.  CSS does not act on your template but the rendered html as seen in your Browser. Provide the portion of the html that  renders your image.  If you can't then use Your browser Dev Tools to poke around the rendered output to see how your div behaves as you adjust the CSS.

Comment: well its the html template for that component but idk how I could post the actual html

Comment: In your browser, right click the zone that's causing you grief and Select `Inspect`  that should open up your browser's Dev Tools and highlight a specific line of HTML.  From there you need to find and select the `div` that's causing your issue and copy the associated HTML.  But more importantly you should see the rendered HTML and see how the css is acting on it.